# wpf combobox isfocued trigger does not work

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am trying to change the border color when a combobox gets keyboard focus with the following code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TextBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <!--<Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />-->
    <Setter Property="IsEditable" Value="False"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource FocusedOnSolidBorderBrush}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works fine.
However, if I use a control template as follows it stops working. The border color change won't show any more.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Grid x:Name="grid">
        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2"  x:Name="ToggleButton" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ClickMode="Press" />
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,3,23,3" x:Name="ContentSite" Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />
        <Popup IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}" Placement="Bottom" x:Name="Popup" Focusable="False" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Slide">
            <Grid MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}" x:Name="DropDown" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" Background="{DynamicResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" CornerRadius="3,3,3,3" />
                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" Style="{DynamicResource NuclearScrollViewer}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionTextBrushKey}}">
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

It looks like something in the template overwrite the trigger specified in the combobox style.
Can anyone tell me which part of the control template need to be changed and why?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new `ControlTemplate` does not define a border and does not bind to the `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` properties, so obviously you won't see and border when the focus changes.

In other words, your trigger still works and changes the property values as expected, but there are no UI elements that bind to the new values. You could easily fix that by adding a border to your control template and bind to these properties. For example:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <!-- ... -->
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Adi, thanks for the answer. It works great. I learned something new. very much appreciate your help.